# Spring ElasticSearch sort by sum of document score plus nested documents score

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nosql, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have 2 document Cafe Meal:

```
@Document(indexName = Indices.CAFE_INDEX)
@Data
public class CafeDocument {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private Long id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String addressLine;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<MealDocument> meals = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Document(indexName = Indices.MEAL_INDEX)
@Data
public class MealDocument {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private Long cafeId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private Long cafeId;
}
```

I also have a BoolQueryBuilder that looks like this:

```
    public SearchHits<CafeDocument> findCafeDocuments(String filter) throws DataAccessResourceFailureException {
    BoolQueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

    filter = filter.toLowerCase();
    builder.must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .should(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(filter)
                    .field("name", 4)
                    .field("addressLine", 2)
                    .field("postalCode", 1)
                    .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE)
            )
            .should(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("meals", QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(filter)
                    .field("meals.name", 30)
                    .field("meals.description", 2)
                    .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE), ScoreMode.Total)
            ));
    NativeSearchQueryBuilder qb = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
    qb.withQuery(builder);
    return operations.search(qb.build(), CafeDocument.class, IndexCoordinates.of( Indices.CAFE_INDEX));
}
```

What i want to get is list of sorted cafes based on the sum of total points that the cafe got plus the total points of meals that have this cafe.

Currently this code filters out cafes that are not related to the filer by no matter how much i increase the boost number, there is not changes in sorting.

Is there a way to fix it? I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: can you provide result of this query builder? I mean in JSON format that will be sent to Elasticsearch API?